# How do I fix "Uncaught TypeError: $(".flexNav").flexNav() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexnav

I'm getting the "Uncaught TypeError" in a custom file that's initializing flexNav with this object:

```
function setupFlexnav() {
// flexnav setup and options
//var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
//if (!isIE) {
    $(".flexnav").flexNav({
    'animationSpeed': 0,
    'transitionOpacity': false,
    'buttonSelector': '.menu-button',
    'hoverIntent': true,
    'hoverIntentTimeout': 100,
    'calcItemWidths': false,
    'hover': true
});
//}

//other custom code follows, but error is thrown on $(".flexnav").flexNav
}
//initialize flexnav
$document.ready(function () {
    setupFlexnav();
});
```

The 'setupFlexNav()' method is called elsewhere in this file, and is wrapped up in $document.ready() {...}, which should stop flexNav() from being called until jQuery has been loaded. 
BundleConfig is loading jQuery-1.10.2.js before my jquery.flexnav-custom.js script, but is loading a jQuery-1.11.3.js file after these 2 files.

I would wonder if loading 2 versions of jQuery on the same page would cause the "Uncaught TypeError" to be thrown, but this code has been unchanged for 6 months in Source Control. I haven't been getting this flexNav() error until today, so something else must be causing the error besides the initialization of flexnav. I just don't know that something is. What would cause my given code to start throwing this error? THANKS!

Comment: Yes, loading more than one version of jQuery can cause conflicts - however your error message gives me the impression that the problem involves flexNav() being called before the plugin is loaded. If you are wrapping it in a jQuery ready statement and still getting this error, then open your console and type  flexNav() into the console and hit enter. You should get an object returned that contains the flexNav() object. If you dont, then your plugin script is not loading.

Comment: Actually, loading two versions of jQuery on a page is possible in `noConflict` mode. But the error you're getting has nothing to do with that. It just says that at the point you're trying to run `flexNav()` function, it was not yet defined. And it gets defined inside the plugin, when you load it. So you need to load the plugin first, call function after. Easiest way to achieve it is to wrap your function inside a `$(window).load(function(){/*code here*/})` wrapper. `$(document).ready()` happens sooner and your plugin is not loaded yet. It will be loaded on `$(window).load()`, though.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu: I double-checked my BundleConfig.cs file, and I'm loading jQuery first, followed by 2 flexnav scripts, and then the custom file (main.js), that has the above code. I changed '$document.ready' to '$(window).load(function() { setupFlexnav(); });', and I'm still getting the '$(...)flexNav is not a function' error.

Comment: @SammyPayne are you using this in WordPress? If so, please refer to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101064/45169). If not, please add a [mcve]. From what you're saying, you're doing things in the proper order, so it should work. Allow us to inspect the issue.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, after looking over my code one more time, I realized that loading 2 versions of jQuery was causing the issue. I omitted the v1.10.2 file and kept the v1.11.3 file, and ensured jquery.flexnav-custom.js was loaded after that. Flexnav() worked fine after reorganizing my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over my code one more time, I realized that the order of my scripts was indeed causing the issue. The old version of jQuery (1.10.2) loaded before jquery.flexnav-custom.js, which is fine, but the new version (1.11.3) loaded after these scripts. I omitted the older file, loaded the newer file before the flexnav script, and rebuilt the project. The error went away.